# How many words of length $10$ are there in which not all of the vowels A, E, I, O, U appear?

Tags: combinatorics, inclusion-exclusion, combinatorics-on-words

The word can have every letter as long as A,E,I,O,U aren't all in the same word.

Can this be the number of all words of length $10$ without all vowels?

$$ 21^{10}+ \sum_{i=1}^4  {10\choose i} 5^i \cdot 21^{10-i} + \sum_{i=5}^{10} {5\choose 4}{10\choose i} 4^i $$

(all consonant words + all words with less than $4$ vowels + all words with $5$ nonrepeated vowels or more)

Is this correct? If there is a simpler way, I would appreciate.

Comment: This is hard to follow. Did you forget to mention that your words were meant to have length $10$?  I don't understand the two sums...I'd have expected to see terms with different signs, as one gets by using Inclusion-exclusion.

Comment: yes it's length 10, sry

Comment: first all consonant words, then the for words with i (<=4) vowels i choose i of the 10 places and I have 5^i ways to choose the sequence of letters. then for i>4 vowels i choose from the 5 vowels 4 of them to use, and apply the same logic as last case

Comment: Doesn't make sense.  Do it by Inclusion exclusion.  First count all the words that are missing a particular vowel.  Now subtract off those that are missing a specified pair of vowels.  Then add back those that are missing a specified triple.  Then subtract those that are missing a specified quadruple.

Comment: Thanks. I learned that Principle a week ago I'm still having some dificulties applying it. Thanks once again.

Comment: Please clarify the question.  Do you wish to find words of length $10$ that do not contain all five vowels?

Comment: yes, it's length 10

Comment: Your question could still use some clarification.  Do you mean the word does not contain all five vowels?

Comment: The word can be
- aeiocccccc
- aaaaaaeio
 
It just can't have a,e,i,o,u at the same time

Answer (score 1):

The number of words in which not all the vowels appear is equal to the number of words in which at least one vowel does not appear.

Let $A, E, I, O, U$ be the set of ten-letter words in which, respectively, the letter $a, e, i, o, u$ does not appear.  The set of words in which at least one vowel does not appear is $A \cup E \cup I \cup O \cup U$.   By the [Inclusion-Exclusion Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle),
\begin{align*}
& |A \cup E \cup I \cup O \cup U|\\ 
& = |A| + |E| + |I| + |O| + |U|\\
& \qquad - (|A \cup E| + |A \cup I| + |A \cup O| + |A \cup U| + |E \cup I| + |E \cup O| + |E \cup U| + |I \cup O| + |I \cup U| + |O \cup U|)\\
& \qquad + (|A \cap E \cap I| + |A \cap E \cap O| + |A \cap E \cap U| + |A \cap I \cap O| + |A \cap I \cap U| + |A \cap O \cap U| + |E \cap I \cap O| + |E \cap I \cap U| + |E \cap O \cap U| + |I \cap O \cap U|\\
& \qquad - (|A \cap E \cap I \cap O| + |A \cap E \cap I \cap U| + |A \cap E \cap O \cap U| + |A \cap I \cap O \cap U| + |E \cap I \cap O \cap U|)\\
& \qquad + |A \cap E \cap I \cap O \cap U|
\end{align*}

$|A|$:  If the vowel $a$ does not appear, then each of the ten positions can be filled in $25$ ways.  Thus, $|A| = 25^{10}$.

By symmetry, $$|A| = |E| = |I| = |O| = |U|$$

$|A \cap E|$:  If neither of the vowels $a$ nor $e$ appears, then each of the ten positions can be filled in $24$ ways.  Thus, $|A \cap E| = 24^{10}$.

By symmetry, $$|A \cap E| = |A \cap I| = |A \cap O| = |A \cap U| = |E \cap I| = |E \cap O| = |E \cap U| = |I \cap O| = |I \cap U| = |O \cap U|$$

$|A \cap E \cap I|$:  If none of the vowels $a, e, i$ appears, then each of the ten positions can be filled in $23$ ways.  Thus, $|A \cap E \cap I| = 23^{10}$.

By symmetry,
$$|A \cap E \cap I| = |A \cap E \cap O| = |A \cap E \cap U| = |A \cap I \cap O| = |A \cap I \cap U| = |A \cap O \cap U| = |E \cap I \cap O| = |E \cap I \cap U| = |E \cap O \cap U| = |I \cap O \cap U|$$

$|A \cap E \cap I \cap O|$:  If none of the vowels $a, e, i, o$ appears, there are $22$ ways to fill each of the ten positions.  Hence, $|A \cap E \cap I \cap O| = 22^{10}$.

By symmetry,
$$|A \cap E \cap I \cap O| = |A \cap E \cap I \cap U| = |A \cap E \cap O \cap U| = |A \cap I \cap O \cap U| = |E \cap I \cap O \cap U|$$

$|A \cap E \cap I \cap O \cap U|$:  If none of the vowels $a, e, i, o, u$ appears, there are $21$ ways to fill each of the ten positions.  Hence, $|A \cap E \cap I \cap O \cap U| = 21^{10}$.

Thus, by the Inclusion-Exclusion Principle, the number of ten-letter words in which at least one vowel does not appear is
\begin{align*}
|A \cup E \cup I \cap O \cap U| & = 5 \cdot 25^{10} - 10 \cdot 24^{10} + 10 \cdot 23^{10} - 5 \cdot 22^{10} + 21^{10}\\
& = \binom{5}{1}25^{10} - \binom{5}{2}24^{10} + \binom{5}{3}23^{10} - \binom{5}{4}22^{10} + \binom{5}{5}21^{10}\\
& = \sum_{k = 1}^{5} (-1)^{k - 1}\binom{5}{k}(26 - k)^{10}
\end{align*}
where $\binom{5}{k}$ is the number of ways of excluding $k$ of the $5$ vowels and $(26 - k)^{10}$ is the number of ways to form a ten-letter word with the remaining $26 - k$ letters of the alphabet.